# Activate Checkbox when clicking on element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When I click on an element, it should (only) activate/tick a checkbox, but it doesn't work.

HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="collapsible" name="collapsible" /> <br />
<p class="member">
Activate Checkbox
</p>
```

Javascript:

```
$(".member").on("click", function() { 
    $('input[id $=collapsible]').attr('checked', this.checked); 
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/et7uym09/

Comment: does this solve your problem? http://jsfiddle.net/zsL15wog/1/

Comment: @SametC can you post it as an answer, so I can mark it as solved?

Comment: of course, on my way :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed your code a little bit, you got already the right base.

`this.checked` is not defined in this context, so you have manually set it to true.

```
$(".member").on("click", function() { 
    $('#collapsible').attr('checked', true); 
});
```

also you can use `$('#collapsible').attr('checked', true);` instead of `$('input[id $=collapsible]').attr('checked', true);`

working jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/zsL15wog/5/

if you want to toggle the checked state of the checkbox do something like this:

```
$(".member").on("click", function() {
    var isChecked = $('#collapsible').prop('checked');
    $('#collapsible').attr('checked', !isChecked); 
  });
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zsL15wog/4/

Hope i could clear the things a bit more up :)
If you got other problems with this code, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

What about `<label>`?  Nothing extra necessary (unless you want a little styling on your text).

```html
<label for="collapsible" style="cursor: pointer;">
    Activate Checkbox
    <input type="checkbox" id="collapsible" name="collapsible" />
<label>
```

Comment: It should **only** activate that checkbox. I want no toggle between on/off, this was my problem.

Answer (score -1):

```
    $(".member").on("click", function() { 
    $('#collapsible').attr('checked',true); 
});
```

Please try the above code